# Project Deployment Error - GC Overhead Limit Exceede

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

I am using tomcat as server and eclipse as my IDE and i am using maven

I am getting "`GC Overhead Limit Exceeded`" when i am doing project clean for my spring project.

Comment: Thank you for looking at my question and trying to help. Actually this is the problem which i faced and i thought to share so i posted the problem as question and i have given solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why i am getting above error is because "low memory allocation for VM"

the solution for this is

```
     1.Goto bin folder of Tomcat.
     2.Increase the size of the permgen in catalina.sh file

     Eg: CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms1024m -Xmx10246m -XX:NewSize=256m 
          -XX:MaxNewSize=356m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=356m"
```

Add the above line in the top of catalina.sh file and restart tomcat (even if doestn't work restart your eclipse also). It worked for me